# Поле ввода над клавиатурой как в "Whats UP" или "Вконтакте". Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

как сделать такое поле ввода, которое будет выпадать над клавиатурой?

В какую сторону копать? Заранее спасибо [image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFQbj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Врятли оно выпадает над клавиатурой. Скорее всего экран имеет такую структуру:

```
[ActionBar] height = wrap_content; layout_weight = 0;
[ScrollView/RecyclerView/ListView] height = 0dp; layout_weight = 1;
[EditText] height = wrap_content; layout_weight = 0;
```

Из нашей разметки понятно, что [ActionBar] и [EditText] занимают столько сколько надо, а [ScrollView/RecyclerView/ListView] растягивается на все оставшееся пространство. При этом [EditText] всегда будет в самом низу активити.
Добавим в манифесте для нашего activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

и после того, как мы будем открывать клавиатуру, наш программный экран будет сжиматься по высоте на высоту клавиатуры, но из-за разметки наш [EditText] будет строго над клавиатурой.

Пример Activity в манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Пример разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/llMain"
android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/SaveButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```